# Why "--nodetach" option is needed for xsel when it is started from systemd unit?

Tags: systemd, x11, tmux

I'm trying to adopt [Alexey Samoshkin's approach](https://medium.com/hackernoon/tmux-in-practice-copy-text-from-remote-session-using-ssh-remote-tunnel-and-systemd-service-dd3c51bca1fa) to copy text from remote tmux session into local clipboard. I'm using `xsel` instead of `xclip`, and systemd user service instead of system one. Here is my working configuration:

`/etc/systemd/user/xsel.socket:`

```
[Unit]
Description=xsel network listener socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=54793
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

`/etc/systemd/user/xsel@.service:`

```
[Unit]
Description=xsel network listener service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/xsel --input --clipboard --nodetach

StandardInput=socket
StandardOutput=socket
```

xsel version 1.2.0
systemd 245 (245.6-8-arch)

Everything works as expected, but only with `--nodetach` option. Without this option clipboard doesn't change at all. Would you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

If a service detaches then it cannot write to `stdout` any more. So the `--nodetach` is needed for keeping `stdout` (and being able to redirect it).